# JSONParser getting complete JSON file With curly brackets

Tags: android, json

i am trying to implement sample JSON data App that Gets JSON data from server

i am Getting complete JSON file whats wrong with my coding ?

i am following an youtube tutorial but he did successfully but i am getting complete JSON File

this is JSON server side file

```
{
"movies" :[
{
 "movie" : "Avenger",
"year" : 2012
}
]
}
```

and this is code from android app

```
package com.yog.jsonparser;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnHit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHit);
         tvData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);
btnHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new JSONTask().execute("http://myDomainName.com/getData.txt");
    }
});
    }

    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        URI url;
        StringBuffer buffer;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params){
         try{

             //URL OF REQUESTED PAGE
             url=new URI(params[0]);
             connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(params[0]).openConnection());
             connection.connect();
             InputStream stream=connection.getInputStream();
             reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
              buffer=new StringBuffer();
             String line;
             while((line =reader.readLine())!=null){
                 buffer.append(line);
             }
             String finalJSON=buffer.toString();
             JSONObject parentOject = new JSONObject(finalJSON);
             JSONArray parentArray = parentOject.getJSONArray("movies");
             JSONObject finalObject= parentArray.getJSONObject(0);
             String movieName= finalObject.getString("movie");
             int year=finalObject.getInt("year");
           return movieName + "-" + year;
         } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {


             if(connection !=null){
                 connection.disconnect();
             }
             try{
                 if(reader !=null){
                     reader.close();
                 }
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

         }

         return null;

     }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            tvData.setText(buffer.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

current Output :

{"movies" :[{ "movie" : "Avenger","year" : 2012}]}

Expected output : 
  Avenger
  2012

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i am getting this output {"movies" :[{ "movie" : "Avenger","year" : 2012}]}

Comment: and i want  Avenger 2012 as output only :_: @EricB.

Comment: Thanks a lot @EricB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onPostExecute` method as below.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    tvData.setText(s);
}
```

Here `s` will be return statement of `doInBackground`. "**movieName + "-" + year;**"

Comment: ohh shit :( Small mistake extreamly sorry guys :( for such nooby que. :_: 


Thanks a lot BRO

Comment: @YogeshGosavi ha haa.. It happens sometimes.. ;-)

Comment: :P yup when you are new to any Environment :3 :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `{"movies" :[{ "movie" : "Avenger","year" : 2012}]}` in the `TextView` because you are setting the buffer's output to the `TextView`. Change your `onPostExecute` like this:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if(s != null){
            tvData.setText(s);
            }else{
            //// Some error occurred
            tvData.setText(buffer.toString());
            }

        }
```